# Python3.4: unable to access the variables in the method which is definded in the same class

Tags: python, python-3.x

Have written a simple code like this:

```
class Operations:
    #global a,b
    a=1
    b=2 


    def __init__(self):
        print(self,"object has been created")


    def add(self):
        #a = 2
        #b = 3
        return a+b

    obj1=Operations()
    sum=obj1.add()
    print(sum).
```

when i run this code, am getting this error `NameError: name 'a' is not defined.`

can you please explain why variables `a` and `b` are not accessible in the method 'add' which is defined in the same class?

Note:when am declaring variables as a `global`, am able to access the variables inside the 'add' method.

Comment: Don't you mean `self.a` and `self.b`? You may want them to be *instance*, rather than *class*, attributes - set them in `__init__` so you can do e.g. `Operations(3, 4).add()` and get `7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the class reference

```
Value= self.a + self.b
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `self` keyword.

### What does `self` do?

```
a = 1

class Operations:
  a = 2

  def fun1(self):
    return a

  def fun2(self):
    return self.a

obj = Operations()
print(obj.fun1())
print(obj.fun2())
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

### Solution for you case:

```
class Operations:
  a=1
  b=2   

  def __init__(self):
    print(self,"object has been created")

  def add(self):
    return self.a + self.b

obj1=Operations()
print(obj1.add())
```

Output:

```
<__main__.Operations object at 0x100663588> object has been created
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the answer that you need? if you're writing a *class*, use `self.value` instead `global value`:

```
class Operations:

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        print(self, "object has been created")

    def add(self):
        return self.a + self.b

obj1 = Operations()
print(obj1.add())
```